# sql query records pair of two

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this one below where the records are basically pair of two (same ID1 and ID2) but different Note and Status (some times).
I need to select all the records that at the same time have the field Note equal to "Ready to QC" and the field Status equal to 1, and the records with the field Note equal to "Ready for Cataloging" have Status 0.

```
ID1,   ID2,      Note,                      Status
3,     22,       Ready for QC,                1
3,     22,       Ready for Cataloging,        0
36,    22,       Ready for QC,                1
36,    22,       Ready for Cataloging,        1
63,    22,       Ready for QC,                1
63,    22,       Ready for Cataloging,        0
67,    67,       Ready for QC,                0
67,    67,       Ready for Cataloging,        0
```

Any suggestions? Thank you. Giovanni

Comment: Welcome to SO!  When posting questions be sure to post code you've tried.  It helps us understand your approach and maybe we can fix something simple.  Otherwise include question, example data and expected output as it helps set the context of the question.

Comment: also post expected result as text

Answer (score 4):

I think you want all the ID1 and ID2 of such records where both conditions exist..

It does assume a uniqueness for each ID1, ID2, Note, Status  (meaning there can't be two identical records in the table)

```
SELECT ID1, ID2, count(*) cnt
FROM Table
WHERE (Note = "Ready to QC" and status = 1) 
    OR(note = "Ready for Cataloging" and Status 0)
GROUP BY ID1, ID2
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: I suppose you could have a case where you have two records that meet the first condition and none that meet the second, and then the query would return those records (incorrectly).

Answer (score 0):

This one is longer but accounts for duplicates:

```
SELECT t1.id1, t1.id2, t1.note, t1.status
FROM
(SELECT *
 FROM t
 WHERE note = 'Ready for QC'
 AND status = 1) t1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT *
 FROM t
 WHERE note = 'Ready for Cataloging'
 AND status = 0) t2
ON t1.id1 = t2.id1
AND t1.id2 = t2.id2
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. Since my table is built on fly by two inner join. I repeat this long selection twice, but it is pretty ugly. Any suggestions?              select hev.HistEventID as ID, hev.EventName as EName, hev.DateLabel as DLabel from HistEvents as hev 
inner join UserFieldXrefs as ufx on hev.HistEventID = ufx.ID and ContextID = 37
inner join UserFields as uf on uf.UserFieldID = ufx.UserFieldID
where (uf.UserFieldName = 'Ready for QC' and substring(ufx.fieldvalue,1,1) = '1' )